# Replace occurances of Enum values in a string with the index of the Enum value for String comparison

Tags: c#, string, enums, compare

I have an enum where the items are meaningfully ordered:

```
enum MyEnum
{
   LORRY,
   BIKE,
   AMBULANCE,
   CAR
};
```

I then have some strings such as:

```
"1 CAR AND A LORRY"
"1 LORRY AND A BIKE"
"1 AMBULANCE AND A BIKE"
"1 LORRY AND A AMBULANCE"
```

Sorting these strings alphabetically would yield:

```
"1 AMBULANCE AND A BIKE"
"1 CAR AND A LORRY"
"1 LORRY AND A AMBULANCE"
"1 LORRY AND A BIKE"
```

But I wish to sort the strings according to the ordering of my Enum. So my result should be:

```
"1 LORRY AND A BIKE"
"1 LORRY AND A AMBULANCE"
"1 AMBULANCE AND A BIKE"
"1 CAR AND A LORRY"
```

I figured that I could replace each occurance of the enum values in the strings with the enum index and use the new strings in string.Compare() to achieve the correct ordering. Problem is, how do I replace the strings with the indexes to achieve:

```
"1 0 AND A 1"
"1 0 AND A 2"
"1 2 AND A 1"
"1 3 AND A 0"
```

i.e.

```
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            TreeNode tx = x as TreeNode;
            TreeNode ty = y as TreeNode;
    
            string s1 = tx.Text;
            string s2 = tx.Text;
            
            // What Goes here to replace the enum values in the strings with the enum index?
    
            // I tried this but the replace seems not to work
            MyEnum[] myEnums= Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToArray();
            for (int i = positions.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                MyEnum myEnum = myEnums[i];
                string str = myEnum.ToString();
                string index = ((int)myEnum).ToString();

                s1.Replace(str, index);
                s2.Replace(str, index);
            }
            return string.Compare(s1, s2);
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at `string.Replace()` and `enum.ToString()` and `string.Contains()` ???

Comment: I've tried but can't get it working, hence the request for help. See update above. Thanks

Comment: Look again; `Replace()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the calling string.

Comment: I feel dumb. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you can work on:

- Get a list of the Enumerator's members names as string
- Order the array of strings based on values determined by the content of the list of names
- Consider only words that match a member of the enumerator
- Give more *value* to a word based on its position inside the string: when found in the first position, a word has *maximum value*; the *value* progressively decreases for each position after the first. The formula is just:

  ```
  double value += [position] * (int.MaxValue / Math.Exp([Index] * 2))
  ```

use any other expression that decreases in value when the position evaluated increases. This one has a limit of ~350 positions in each single string; after that, `Math.Exp()` returns `0`.

This form has clearly a limitation, strings that don't contain words that match the name of a member of the enumerator are listed first but not ordered in any way.
It was not part of the question. Modify as required.

```
string[] phrases = new[] {
    "1 LORRY AND A BIKE",
    "1 AMBULANCE AND AN BIKE FOLLOW BY A LORRY",
    "1 LORRY AND AN AMBULANCE",
    "1 CAR AND A BIKE",
    "1 AMBULANCE AND A BIKE",
    "1 LORRY AND A LORRY",
    "1 NO CARS OR BIKES",
    "1 AMBULANCE AND A BLUE CAR AND A RED CAR AND A WHITE CAR",
    "1 CAR AND ANOTHER FANCY LORRY"
};

var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(StringyEnum)).ToList();

var ordered = phrases.OrderBy(sv => sv.Split().Where(enumNames.Contains)
    .Select((s, i) => (s, i)).Sum(n =>
        (enumNames.IndexOf(n.s) + 1) * (int.MaxValue / Math.Exp(n.i*2))
    ));
```

This orders the string as:

```
1 NO CARS OR BIKES
1 LORRY AND A LORRY
1 LORRY AND A BIKE
1 LORRY AND AN AMBULANCE
1 AMBULANCE AND A BIKE
1 AMBULANCE AND AN BIKE FOLLOW BY A LORRY
1 AMBULANCE AND A BLUE CAR AND A RED CAR AND A WHITE CAR
1 CAR AND ANOTHER FANCY LORRY
1 CAR AND A BIKE
```